# How to stop Audio File Played through Apple Quicktime plugin in a webpage

Tags: quicktime, multimedia, jquery-dialog, audio-player

i am playing audio file through the code below in a jQuery Dialog through Quicktime.
Everything is working fine but what i want to do is when i close the Dialog i want the audio file to stop too. in real its keep playing.

Code:

```
//Listen Music
$('.listenMusic').live('click', function(){
    if($('div.ui-dialog').length){
        $('div.ui-dialog').remove();
    }
    var path = $(this).attr('rel');
    var $dialog = $('<div>', {
        title: Listen
        }).dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        modal: true,
        width: 400,
        height: 100
    });
    var tab = '<table width="90%" style="margin: 10px 10%;"><tr><td><object codebase="http://www.apple.com/qtactivex/qtplugin.cab#version=6,0,2,0" classid="clsid:02BF25D5-8C17-4B23-BC80-D3488ABDDC6B"><param value="'+path+'" name="SRC"><param value="true" name="AUTOPLAY"><param value="true" name="CONTROLLER"><embed pluginspage="http://www.apple.com/quicktime/download/" controller="true" style="height:20px;width:300px;background-color:#D9EBFB" autoplay="true" target="myself" src="'+path+'"></object></td></tr></table>';
    $('<div id="updateContent">').html(tab).appendTo($dialog);
    $dialog.dialog('open');
    return false;

});
```

this is the tag i used in above code

```
<object codebase="http://www.apple.com/qtactivex/qtplugin.cab#version=6,0,2,0" 
classid="clsid:02BF25D5-8C17-4B23-BC80-D3488ABDDC6B"><param value="'+path+'"  
name="SRC"><param value="true" name="AUTOPLAY"><param value="true" 
name="CONTROLLER"><embed pluginspage="http://www.apple.com/quicktime/download/" 
controller="true" style="height:20px;width:300px;background-color:#D9EBFB"    
autoplay="true" target="myself" src="'+path+'"></object>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why dont you just do this

Give "id" to your table

```
'<table id="myPlayer" width="90%" style="margin: 10px 10%;">
```

capture jquery Dialog close icon(*)  event

```
 $('div.ui-dialog').live("dialogclose", function(){
   if($("#myPlayer").length){
       $("#myPlayer").remove();
   }
   }):
```

This will remove it from dom which means your audio file is no longer exists so it will stop playing.